# I can't add labels to my pd pie chart

Tags: python

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test_Pos':[65.44, 23.22, 11.34], 'Test_Neg':[22.55, 65.13, 12.32]}, index=['Positive','Negative','Others'] )
df.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, figsize=(16, 8))
```

I can't label the charts. I want to put percentages on the chart. How do I do this using pandas?

[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autopct` argument.

**Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test_Pos': [65.44, 23.22, 11.34], 'Test_Neg': [22.55, 65.13, 12.32]},
                  index=['Positive', 'Negative', 'Others'])
df.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, figsize=(16, 8), autopct='%.2f', labels=df.index, fontsize=10)
```

[image]